# GAE + nosetest error: TypeError: order() expects a Property or query Order;

Tags: python, google-app-engine

I have a small python app in google app engine which works and can be manually tested.

I want to start driving the development using tests and I'm trying to use nosetests --with-gae

but I'm getting the following error on testing my handlers:

```
TypeError: order() expects a Property or query Order; received DateTimeProperty('date')
```

my models are using ndb datastore.

The offending class is:

```
import datetime
from google.appengine.ext import ndb

class Event(ndb.Model):
    date = ndb.DateTimeProperty(indexed=True)
    description = ndb.StringProperty(indexed=True)

    @staticmethod
    def get_next_event_by_date():
        next_event = Event.query(Event.date >= datetime.datetime.now()).order(Event.date).fetch(1)
        return next_event[0] if next_event else None
```

If I remove the order clause from the Event query then the test passes OK.

Anyone got any ideas what might be the problem.

Cheers

Neil

Comment: The query looks fine, though I would have though you should use a classmethod rather than a static method.  Does this query run fine outside of nosetest ?

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion - once I get my tests running I'll refactor!. The query runs fine outside of the tests.

Comment: What does your test do? Are you setting 'Event.date' instead of an instance's value somewhere?

Comment: The test just checks the response from the get method of a handler. The query which blows up is in the handler.

Further investigation showed that this version of the query worked in both the app and the tests:

`Event.query(Event.date >= datetime.datetime.now()).order(+Event.date).fetch(1)`

Note the '+' before Event.date

Still not sure why the version without the '+' works in the app not not in the tests. Any thoughts?

Comment: Adding the '+' will call model.Property's \_\_pos__ method to be called, which returns a PropertyOrder. If it's the property directly, then a PropertyOrder is created using the propery's name, or at least that's what's meant to happen. It seems that checking your Event.date is a subclass of model.Property is failing. There's definitely no mocking going on in the test?

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions. My current tests use testbed but I think the problem predates this. There is no mocking of the Event class.

The code is visible [here](https://github.com/neilbmclaughlin/agileyorkshire-events) if you feel it would be useful to take a look.

Now that I know what the workaround is I'm happy to have documented it on Stackoverflow. Please feel free to walk away at this point unless you are professionally interested in the reason for the behaviour :)