# How to order NDB query by the key?

Tags: python-2.7, google-app-engine, app-engine-ndb

I try to use task queues on Google App Engine. I want to utilize the Mapper class shown in the App Engine documentation "[Background work with the deferred library](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/articles/deferred)". 
I get an exception on the ordering of the query result by the key

```
def get_query(self):
    ...
    q = q.order("__key__")
    ...
```

Exception:

```
File "C:... mapper.py", line 41, in get_query
    q = q.order("__key__")
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\google_appengine\google\appengine\ext\ndb\query.py", line 1124, in order
    'received %r' % arg)
TypeError: order() expects a Property or query Order; received '__key__'
INFO     2017-03-09 11:56:32,448 module.py:806] default: "POST /_ah/queue/deferred HTTP/1.1" 500 114
```

The article is from 2009, so I guess something might have changed.
My environment: Windows 7, Python 2.7.9, Google App Engine SDK 1.9.50

There are [somewhat similar questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19510278/gae-nosetest-error-typeerror-order-expects-a-property-or-query-order) about ordering in NDB on SO.
What bugs me this code is from the official doc, presumably updated in Feb 2017 (recently) and posted by someone within top 0.1 % of SO users by reputation.

So I must be doing something wrong. What is the solution?

Comment: try `q = q.order(self.KIND.key)`

Comment: `ndb.delete_multi` requires a list of `key`, so make sure `map ` returns a Key in `to_delete`

Answer (score 1):

Bingo.
Avinash Raj is correct. If it were an answer I'd accept it.
Here is the full class code

```
#!/usr/bin/python2.7
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
from google.appengine.ext import deferred
from google.appengine.ext import ndb
from google.appengine.runtime import DeadlineExceededError
import logging

class Mapper(object):
    """
    from https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/ndb/queries
    corrected with suggestions from Stack Overflow
    http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42692319/how-to-order-ndb-query-by-the-key
    """
    # Subclasses should replace this with a model class (eg, model.Person).
    KIND = None

    # Subclasses can replace this with a list of (property, value) tuples to filter by.
    FILTERS = []

    def __init__(self):
        logging.info("Mapper.__init__: {}")
        self.to_put = []
        self.to_delete = []

    def map(self, entity):
        """Updates a single entity.
        Implementers should return a tuple containing two iterables (to_update, to_delete).
        """
        return ([], [])

    def finish(self):
        """Called when the mapper has finished, to allow for any final work to be done."""
        pass

    def get_query(self):
        """Returns a query over the specified kind, with any appropriate filters applied."""
        q = self.KIND.query()
        for prop, value in self.FILTERS:
            q = q.filter(prop == value)
        if __name__ == '__main__':
            q = q.order(self.KIND.key) # the fixed version. The original q.order('__key__') failed
            # see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42692319/how-to-order-ndb-query-by-the-key
        return q

    def run(self, batch_size=100):
        """Starts the mapper running."""
        logging.info("Mapper.run: batch_size: {}".format(batch_size))
        self._continue(None, batch_size)

    def _batch_write(self):
        """Writes updates and deletes entities in a batch."""
        if self.to_put:
            ndb.put_multi(self.to_put)
            self.to_put = []
        if self.to_delete:
            ndb.delete_multi(self.to_delete)
            self.to_delete = []

    def _continue(self, start_key, batch_size):
        q = self.get_query()
        # If we're resuming, pick up where we left off last time.
        if start_key:
            key_prop = getattr(self.KIND, '_key')
            q = q.filter(key_prop > start_key)
        # Keep updating records until we run out of time.
        try:
            # Steps over the results, returning each entity and its index.
            for i, entity in enumerate(q):
                map_updates, map_deletes = self.map(entity)
                self.to_put.extend(map_updates)
                self.to_delete.extend(map_deletes)
                # Do updates and deletes in batches.
                if (i + 1) % batch_size == 0:
                    self._batch_write()
                # Record the last entity we processed.
                start_key = entity.key
            self._batch_write()
        except DeadlineExceededError:
            # Write any unfinished updates to the datastore.
            self._batch_write()
            # Queue a new task to pick up where we left off.
            deferred.defer(self._continue, start_key, batch_size)
            return
        self.finish()
```